# TransactionTimeout not working properly

Tags: c#, transactions

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = TransactionScopeManager.GetTransactionScope(Settings.Import.TimeOut))
{
    Logger.Trace.DebugFormat("Import Deduction timeout: <{0}>", Settings.Import.TimeOut);
    //Logger shows "Import Deduction timeout: <30>"
    //more code
}
```

But transaction always run only 10 minutes.
I have changed section :

> ```
>  <system.transactions>
>      <machineSettings maxTimeout=″01:30:00″/>
>  </system.transactions>
> ```

But it still continues failing after 10 minutes.
Why?

Kindly help.

Comment: @Jermy provided you with an answer, but if you need a transaction to run over 10 minutes I'd suggest you reevaluate your design. I usually think about my transactions in milliseconds, or seconds on the high end.

Comment: In transaction there's import of huge file from another system. That's why I need so long transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149852(v=vs.90).aspx:

> In machine config, there is a value that caps the timeouts. By
>   default, it is 10 minutes. So, if you set a timeout greater than 10
>   mins, in System.Transactions, your value will be ignored and the
>   system will act as if the timeout is 10 minutes.
>
> See
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.configuration.machinesettingssection.maxtimeout.aspx
>   and
>
> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowstransactionsprogramming/thread/ba508c2b-af91-490c-a05c-e4bf92f81cc6
>   and
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/ajit/archive/2008/06/18/override-the-system-transactions-default-timeout-of-10-minutes-in-the-code.aspx

Comment: I have added this parameter early (see ask).
Should I restart the computer?

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy, i fixed this issue. There's two foldres named Framework and Framework64. First I changed maxTimeout in machine.config in Framework folder. But then I try to change it in Framework64 folder and it works!